# Look ahead Assertions in QregularExpression

Tags: c++, regex, qt

Does `QRegularExpression` provide lookahead asssertion in its regex engine?
i have tested this example and i got no matched string.

```
QString s = "px1 pt 2px 3em 4px";
QRegularExpression re("\\d(?=px)");
auto match = re.match(s);
qDebug()<< match.lastCapturedIndex();
```

and the result was 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QRegularExpression`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html) uses PCRE regex, so it supports lookaheads, and lookbehinds, and even lazy quantifiers. In your case, there is only a whole match value, without captures, so use `match.captured(0)` to access the value.

Use

```
QRegularExpression re("\\d+(?=px)");
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = re.globalMatch("px1 pt 2px 3em 4px");
QStringList words;
while (i.hasNext()) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    QString word = match.captured(0);
    words << word;
}
// words contains "2", "4"
```

The `\d+(?=px)` pattern matches 1+ digits only if followed with `px` literal character sequence.

Comment: your right.Qt support lookaheads.but your code doesn't work.i founded that "px" expression should be in parentheses.so i edited your answer.thank u very much for your answer.

Comment: No, you do not need to use capturing group around `px`. It is not necessary because you want to get numbers only and they are stored in `match.captured(0)` (zeroth item).

Comment: You did not use my code, ok, but still there is no point in capturing `px`. Capture the digits then.

Comment: yes.your code was correct.i think i should review my code.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have an extra backward slash in your second line? why not use

```
\d+(?=px)
```

instead of

```
\\d(?=px)
```

The reason why I added a + is because **\d** would only capture 1 digit, **+** allows it to capture one or more

I'm not sure if lookahead works in that regex engine but if it doesn't you can use this

```
(\d+)px
```

See the following for examples:

https://regex101.com/r/HgCwXp/1

Comment: because slash is escape character.thank u for your example https://regex101.com/r/HgCwXp/1 it is really great site.

Comment: Why are you escaping  \d though? if you escape \ in \d then your regex is now looking for literal \ followed by d, not the meaning of \d (which is a range from 0 to 9, [0-9]), view https://regex101.com/r/yCDXNW/1

Comment: @Maslo: because within a C++ string, backslash needs to be escaped. In a string `\d` would be an escape sequence like `\n` for newline (not that `\d` is a valid escape sequence, but that's beside the point)